# What is the potential issue with ProGuard and ClassValue on Android 14?

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8, android-14

In the documentation for behaviour changes when targeting Android 14, there is [an issue mentioned related to ProGuard and ClassValue](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#core-libraries):

> **ProGuard issues**: In some cases, the addition of the `java.lang.ClassValue` class causes an issue if you try to shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app using ProGuard. The problem originates with a Kotlin library that changes runtime behaviour based on whether `Class.forName("java.lang.ClassValue")` returns a class or not. If your app was developed against an older version of the runtime without the `java.lang.ClassValue` class available, then these optimizations might remove the `computeValue` method from classes derived from `java.lang.ClassValue`.

From the very little information given, I'm struggling to understand exactly what this means and the potential impact - and can't find more detail anywhere. The "Kotlin library" is not named, but I think it may be `kotlinx.serialization`, based on [this issue I found](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/2119) - if so, then the "change in runtime behaviour" is just about more efficient caching. I also don't know what is meant by "the runtime" (is this Android version (actual/target)? Compile-time JDK version? Proguard/R8 version? Library version?)

If I developed an app which targeted an earlier version of Android, then obviously I won't have any classes which extend from `java.lang.ClassValue`, because that class didn't exist. So how could I face a problem with the overridden `computeValue` method when changing to target Android 14?

(By the way, when it says "ProGuard" I'm assuming this relates to R8 as well, not only ProGuard itself, although that's not explicitly clear from the docs.)

Comment: I agree the documentation is very frustrating. Write clearly and give us the information for how we mitigate the risk :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the details are in the [issue you referenced](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/2119), and the [issue should be fixed], so you should ensure you use a version of `kotlinx.serialization` with the fix.

The underlying issue is that R8 can remove the `computeValue` method when compiling with a `compileSdk` of 33 and below, as `java.lang.ClassValue` is not present in `android.jar` so ``computeValue` is not seen as a library override.

You can move to a `compileSdk` of 34 to get a library with `java.lang.ClassValue`, see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk.

Comment: Can you please give more clarity if possible? I went through Documentstion, Question, Answer and all links. Can you please tell what exactly I need to search in project to get the usage? Can you tell if I use min version 24, will it give issue or not?

Comment: If you use a version of `kotlinx.serialization` with the fix there should be any issues for any version of `minApi`.

Comment: Still not getting it, but I use this: import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

Comment: There was a typo in my comment I meant "should _not_ be any issues" instead of "should be any issues". A sufficient new version of the dependency will address the issue. If you use `kotlinx.parcelize` and it has a transitive dependency on `kotlinx.serialization` then that i where you will have to check the version. If you are in doubt, then just double check by testing on devices/emulators with different Android versions.